# ElasticSearch analyzer that prioritizes order of term appearance in a search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an object in Elastic which represents a product with two properties: *title* and *category*. Within title I have a field concerning *exact-word* and another with *synonyms*. At search time I am boosting the search of the documents by exact word, but if I have for example a product named "Notebook dell" and "bag Notebook", it's bringing bag notebook first.

I want to prioritize the order of appearance of the search term after passing a custom analyzer, so for example:

- samsung Notebook
- Notebook Dell
- notebook Macbook Pro
- bag notebook

should come as

- Notebook Dell
- notebook Macbook Pro
- bag notebook

Can this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Span First Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-span-first-query.html)

You can add this in you clause to boost documents that start with the search term like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "notebook"
          }
        },
        {
          "span_first": {
            "match": {
              "span_term": {
                "title": "notebook"
              }
            },
            "end": 2,
            "boost" : 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Also `span queries` are not `analyzed` so you have to take care of that because *notebook* and *Notebook* will give different results.

Comment: Oh, that's bad D:, I'll give it a try however.